# PyCharm does not detect test cases running Robot Framework test runner

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

I have a test case named `Test Case A` which I want to debug inner method callings in imported python libraries. I used PyCharm Run/Debug Configurations window to set parameters.

1. Script: `/home/zeinab/Workspace/Test/run.py`
2. Script Parameters: `--testsuite MyDirectory.MyTestSuite --testcases "Test Case A"`
3. Working Directory: `/home/zeinab/Workspace/Test`
4. `Add content roots to PYTHONPATH` and `Add source roots to PYTHONPATH` are checked.

This is the debugger output:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/zeinab/Workspace/lbs-w-report-agent-test/lbs-w/Test/NewTest/run.py --testsuite MyDirectory.MyTestSuite --testcases "Test Case A"
Number of Failed Scenarios: 252
[ ERROR ] Suite 'Scenarios' contains no tests named 'Test Case A' in suite 'MyDirectory.MyTestSuite'.

Try --help for usage information.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

But when I copy/paste the line that debugger is trying to execute, there is no problem in detecting my test case.

`run.py` contains:

```
import argparse


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Robot Test Framework')
    parser.add_argument('--file', metavar='f', default="scenarios", help='get path of root scenario')
    parser.add_argument('--outputdir', metavar='outputdir', default=DEFAULT_REPORT_DIR, nargs='*', help='get directory for saving output files')
    parser.add_argument('--debugfile', metavar='debugfile', default='', nargs='*', help='get file name for saving plain-text log file')
    parser.add_argument('--testsuite', metavar='testsuite', default=list(), nargs='*', help='get names of test suits')
    parser.add_argument('--tags', metavar='tags', default=list(), nargs='*', help='get name of tags')
    parser.add_argument('--critical', metavar='critical', default="", nargs='*', help='get name of tags which should be considered as critical')
    parser.add_argument('--testcases', metavar='testcases', default=list(), nargs='*', help='get name of testCases')
    parser.add_argument('--skip', metavar='skip', default=list(), nargs='*', help='get name of skip testCases')
    parser.add_argument('--loglevel', metavar='loglevel', default="DEBUG", nargs='*', help='get log level')
    parser.add_argument('--listener', metavar="listener", default=list(), nargs='*', help='list of listener classes')
    arguments = parser.parse_args()
    a = run(
        arguments.file,
        listener=arguments.listener,
        outputdir=arguments.outputdir,
        debugfile=arguments.outputdir + "/debugfile.log",
        report=arguments.outputdir + "/report.html",
        log=arguments.outputdir + "/log.html",
        output=arguments.outputdir + "/output.xml",
        include=arguments.tags,
        test=arguments.testcases,
        exclude=arguments.skip,
        critical=arguments.critical,
        suite=arguments.testsuite,
        loglevel=':'.join(arguments.loglevel) if type(arguments.loglevel) == list else arguments.loglevel
    )
    print 'Number of Failed Scenarios:', a
    if a != 0:
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Can you run regular robot script without any issues? Is it just this setup that is causing you problems?

Comment: There is already run.py in robot package which does exactly the same stuff as yours run.py . Still a valid question from @A.Kootstra about what happens in simple debug, maybe config of your debugger has something wrong. You may have a look how it is configured in RED using pydevd (eclipse pydev debugger) to allow simultaneous debug on Robot level and python level, switching from pydevd to pycharm debugger should not be an issue: https://github.com/nokia/RED/blob/master/src/RobotUserScripts/runPyDevDebug.py  http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/user_guide/launching/debug/robot_python_debug.html